# Javascript function called in the manner of func(a)(b)(c)

Tags: javascript

I know it's considered bad practice here to solve homework, so I'm just asking for some direction, since I'm at a total loss. Here is the problem: Define a function add() that adds numbers in a functional manner. For example add(1)(1)(1)(1)(1) returns 5. Second example:

```
var addTwo = add(2);
console.log(addTwo); // 2
console.log(addTwo(3)); // 5
```

Comment: And you're not the first to ask that question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e1qhvnnq/

Comment: A keyword that may help in your search is [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Comment: Note that the second console.log makes no sense, you can't have a variable that is both a number ***and*** a function, it's either or.

Comment: @adeneo was about to say exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the notes it is called currying.  [Here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/2011/functional-javascript-part-4-function-currying) is a simple example of what is going on:

```
// uncurried
var example1 = function (a, b, c) {
    // do something with a, b, and c
};

// curried
var example2 = function(a) {
    return function (b) {
        return function (c) {
            // do something with a, b, and c
        };
    };
};
```

Take a look at the link to get the full picture.  Good luck.